# Where in RAdwords can I specify what country and channel (SEA vs Shopping) I want to investigate?

Tags: r, google-ads-api

I am using the following code to get performance data for my German Google SEA-channel and it works perfectly fine.

However:

1. Rather than only getting data for the *German* channel I also want to get data for my *Austrian* and *Italian* channel.
2. Rather than just getting data for SEA, I also want to get data for my Google Shopping channel.

**Question:** What do I need to change in the code or in the process in order to achieve both of these goals above?

```
library(RAdwords)

google_auth <- doAuth()

body <- statement(select=c('EffectiveFinalUrl ' ,'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Impressions','Date'),
                  report="FINAL_URL_REPORT" ,
                  start="2018-03-01",
                  end="2018-03-31")

data <- getData(clientCustomerId='xxx-xxx-xxx',
                google_auth=google_auth,
                statement=body, 
                transformation = T, 
                changeNames = T)

print(head(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your Google Ads account and campaign structure it is difficult to answer your questions. I hope I can point in the right direction with this answer.

Concerning your second question about the differentiation of Google Text Ads and Google Shopping and can simply add the campaign to your query. In the statement/query of the `FINAL_URL_REPORT`, you can add `CampaignName` as an additional attribute.

```
body <- statement(select=c(`CampaignName`, 'EffectiveFinalUrl' ,'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Impressions','Date'),
                  report="FINAL_URL_REPORT",
                  start="2018-03-01",
                  end="2018-03-31")
```

Now you can distinguish the final URL data based on the campaign level. As Google Search Text and Display Ads are separated from Google Shopping campaigns, this should answer your second question.

Concerning your question about country data either one of the following approaches might help:

A) Use the `Campaign_Location_Target_Report`. This gives you geo location-based data for each of your campaigns.

```
body <- statement(select=c('CampaignName', 'Id', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Impressions','Date'),
                  report="Campaign_Location_Target_Report",
                  start="2018-03-01",
                  end="2018-03-01",compress = T)
```

The `Id` refers to the google geolocation. Google provides a mapping here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting You have to match the Ids to the location name by yourself. The Google API only provides Ids.

B) Use the `AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` and extract the country information from the URL with regex. Your URLs might include a part that identifies the country like ".de" or "/de/". Extract this part of the URL as an additional column and aggregate your data.

```
body <- statement(select=c("CreativeDestinationUrl",
                           "CreativeFinalAppUrls",                             
                           "CreativeFinalMobileUrls",
                           "CreativeFinalUrls",                        
                           "CreativeFinalUrlSuffix",
                           'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Impressions'),
                  report="AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
                  start="2018-03-01",
                  end="2018-03-01",compress = T)
```

C) This suggestion relates to your Google Ads Account/Campaign setup. Split your Google Ads campaign by country in the campaign settings and create a campaign for each country: campaign_1_de, campaign_1_at, campaign_1_it You then can simply query a `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` and compare the data on the campaign level.

I hope that helps!